# Locking / Concurrency Issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking

I have the following C# code:

```
1.    List<BandEdge> bandEdgeList;
2.    
3.    bandEdgeList = CicApplication.BandEdgeCache.Where(row => row.Coater == coater).ToList();
4.    foreach (BandEdge bandEdge in bandEdgeList)
5.       {
6.          ...
7.          ...
8.       }
```

My question is this. Once 'bandEdgeList' is populated on line 3, if another thread modifies the contents of CicApplication.BandEdgeCache, would the contents of 'bandEdgeList' be invalidated? I have a lock in the CicApplication.BandEdgeCache getter / setter. But I'm wondering if I should put a lock around this block of code so that the contents of CicApplication.BandEdgeCache don't change while I'm working with 'bandEdgeList'.

Comment: If `BandEdgeCache` is an editable collection, as well, you could effectively be missing items in your local list, could have items that did not satisfy your `Coater` condition, or could be in your list that are no longer in the `BandEdgeCache` collection in addition to the problems in the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not automatically, but this is still not thread-safe. It could throw a `InvalidOperationException`.

Once `ToList` is called, its saves a copy of those references. But if another thread modifies `BandEdgeCache` while that is happening, bad things happen.

So, you should lock all references to `BandEdgeCache`.

But along the lines of the saved list, that would be safe, but modifying any `BandEdge` isn't thread-safe without some locking.

Answer (score 3):

`bandEdgeList` would be an independent copy (since you are using `ToList()`), so you don't need to lock.

However, as @Daniel A. White commented, you need to lock around the LINQ statement that creates that copy.

Comment: It would be an independent copy, but in order to make it, `BandEdgeCache` will need to be locked.

Comment: I learned something today... I thought the ToList didn't actually make a copy and you had to use ToArray to copy... Thanks Oded.

Comment: @jsobo - it only copy references.

Answer (score 1):

Putting a lock in the getter of CicApplication.BandEdgeCache does not help you if it is returning a reference to the collection.

```
CicApplication.BandEdgeCache{
  get{lock(_myCollection){return _myCollection;}}
}
```

returns the reference but has EXITED the lock once it returns so using the Where() function on the reference to the collection returned by the getter is done OUTSIDE the lock and is not threadsafe. Another thread can quite happily alter the collection while the Where is iterating as the lock is not held - Daniel is correct, an InvalidOperationException will be thrown if another thread alters the collection while you are generating the list.

Once the list has been generated the original collection can be changed without it harming access to the new list.